# How to transform a column in df based on condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with an API to create an ETL and one of my columns called "metadata.to" had nested lists within dictionaries within a list. For example, a print result of the column would display:

```
[NaN, 
[{'raw': '"Kate Grape"', 'email': 'green@grapes.com', 'firstName': 'Kate', 'lastName': 'Grape'}],
 [{'raw': '"Blue Sky"', 'email': 'white@clouds.com'}],
 [{'raw': '"Cement Block"', 'email': 'concrete@cement.com', 'firstName': 'Cement', 'lastName': 'Block}],
 NaN, NaN, NaN,  [{'raw': '"Sahara Desert"', 'email': 'nowater@dusty.com', 'firstName': 'Sahara', 'lastName': 'Desert'}], NaN....]
```

and so on for what equates to about 70 rows

I've successfully extracted the email addresses and put them in a dataFrame called sentTo. There are only 15 email addresses and given that it's an engagement table I'm working with that has different engagement types (such as calls, emails sent, etc.) I don't want to delete the rows that don't have email addresses because they contain call data. How do I successfully map this dataFrame on the original column? I've tried transforming the column itself using a for loop but its returning a list of all of the emails in each row.
My loop:

```
    df['metadata.to'] = df['metadata.to'].replace({np.nan: 'Null'}) #done first
        def mail(data):
          emails =[]
          for x in df['metadata.to']: 
            if x == 'Null':
               continue
            else:
               for a in x:
                 emails.append(a['email'])
          return emails
    df['metadata.to']=df['metadata.to'].map(mail)
```

Note: It was required to convert the NaNs to "Null"

I've also tried the .apply() method and have gotten the same result.

```
    df['metadata.to']=df.apply(mail, axis=1)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What code did you use for the `.apply()` method?

Comment: df['metadata.to']=df.apply(mail, axis=1)

Comment: Is the indentation in your main code block above correct?  It looks like some extra indentation happened for the `def mail()` section and that what's written won't run.  Please confirm the indentation and/or correct the code. It also looks like you're missing a single-quote at the end of Block in the sample data...  and can you provide a sample of what the output data is supposed to look like?

Comment: Also, I think you've misunderstood how to use [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Please check the examples on that link....  but you shouldn't have to reference `df` from within `mail()`.  The only input should be `data`, which is either a column or a row according to the value set for `axis`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to pandas
And use load_dataset to call it

Comment: This might work! Can you explain further?